# convert array value to an object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I convert this array

```
[ { africa: 1 },
  { culture: 1 },
  { feminism: 3 },
  { 'feminists rising': 1 },
  { law: 1 } ]
```

into something like this

```
someObj = {africa: 1, culture: 1, feminism: 3, 'feminists rising': 1, law: 1}
```

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...yourArray)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread the array into [`Object#assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const data = [{"africa":1},{"culture":1},{"feminism":3},{"feminists rising":1},{"law":1}];

const result = Object.assign({}, ...data);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const raw = [
  {
    africa: 1
  },
  {
    culture: 1
  },
  {
    feminism: 3
  },
  {
    'feminists rising': 1
  },
  {
    law: 1
  }
];

console.log(raw.reduce((acc, next) => {
  const key = Object.keys(next)[0];
  acc[key] = next[key];
  return acc;
}, {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const subjects = [
  {africa: 1},
  {culture: 1},
  {feminism: 3},
  {'feminists rising': 1},
  {law: 1}
];
```

Use the `Object.assign()` method to mash a list of the individual objects into an empty array. In order to generate the list from the array of objects, the spread syntax (...) is used.

```
const obj = Object.assign({}, ...subjects);
```